# How to unzip an archive using zlib in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, zlib, unzip

How can I use zlib to unzip an archive in Node.js?

I'm using this in a Lambda function on AWS. I'm pulling down a ziped file that gets created from CodePipeline. Once I download it I can access it's Body property which seems to be a Buffer. How do I extract the files in that zip to the local "tmp" directory?

I'd like to stick with the zlib so I can use the AWS console to edit the code, zlib is installed on Lambda environments by default.

Comment: When you say "ziped" (zipped?) do you mean a .zip file?

Comment: Yes, I'm using AWS CodePipeline with CodeBuild and it is "ziping" artifacts before storing in S3, but it doesn't put the ".zip" on the end of the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zlib by itself does not process .zip files. You need something like [libarchive](https://www.libarchive.org/) or [libzip](https://libzip.org/) for that. (Both of those use zlib for the core compression, decompression, and CRC-32 calculation.)

I looks like they are both part of the [Amazon Linux AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2017.09-packages/).

Comment: Thats Mark. I'll look at spawning a child process from Node.JS to invoke one of those libraries you mentioned from within my Lambda function.